# Why does trying to read data attributes returns undefined in my site?

Tags: jquery, html

I tried this in jsfiddle and it worked however I cannot get data attributes to work in my site. In this case I get "undefined" in the alert:

```
<div data-test="something"></div>
<script>alert($('div').data('test'));</script>
```

What could be the  reason for this?

Comment: Wrap your code with document ready handler.

Comment: I just did it. I had tested it inside document ready and it also didn't work

Comment: `.data()` returns value of the first matched `div` element, if you have other div elements(before the target element), it will fail.

Comment: It's the only element I'm including with this attribute

Comment: @Liso22 did you tried with specific ID or having a class rather than div ?

Comment: @Liso22 `.data()` doesn't filter the elements that have `data-*` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lot of `div's` in your page and `.data()` will alert first div. So You have two options to get the data value.

1. Use the parent div class and alert value.

`$(document).ready(function(){

alert($('div.entry-content').children().data('test'));

});`

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nTtBC/)**</kbd>

**NOTE:** I just used parent div class that you are using in your site.

1. Put some `id` or `class` to the div and use that to alert data value.

**CODE:**

```
<div id="datatest" data-test="something"></div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert($('div#datatest').data('test'));
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE With ID](http://jsfiddle.net/nTtBC/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In jsfiddle you have set dom ready .And i think you just copy paste the code in script tag .

you are missing `dom ready` here

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($('div').data('test'));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have alot of div's on your site but this script only alerts the first div's `data-test`

*edit:* i.e the first one found in DOM

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg26z/1/)

**Solution:** add an id to `div` you want to get `data-test` from

Answer (score 0):

`$('div')` is too general of a selector. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYmkA/1/) with exactly one element, your code runs fine. However, in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYmkA/2/) with multiple elements, your code fails:

```
<div></div>
<div data-test="something"></div>
<script>alert($('div').data('test'));</script>
```

`$('div')` selects every `<div>` on the page, but [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) only gets the value of the *first element in the jQuery collection*:

> ...return the value at the named data store for the *first element* in the set of matched elements.

Therefore, you are trying to get the `data-test` attribute for the first element in the collection, which, in my example above, does not have such an attribute. You need to make you selector more specific, to select the exact element you want. You might try:

- using an `id` on the element and selecting it with `$('div#someIdOnTheDiv')`
- less preferably, grab any `<div>` that has the `data-test` attribute: `$('div[data-test]')`